# Add row to kendo grid in javascript with data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

When adding a new record the user is presented with a modal containing a form to fill out. When clicking OK, the data is saved to the DB and the modal closes. However I now have to add this record to the grid. I can't just refresh the grid from the DB since it could wipe out other changes the user might have made in the grid.

I need to get the data from the various form fields and pass it to the grid as a new row in javascript. I've seen an example where a row was copied from one kendo grid to another, but I can't find anything where a new record is added from scratch client side to a kendo grid. Here's the example copying from one grid to another: [how to add a new row with pre defined data in kendo grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171131/how-to-add-a-new-row-with-pre-defined-data-in-kendo-grid)

Basically what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
var newRow = {field1: $("#field1").val(), field2: $("#field2").val(), field3: $("#field3").val()};

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.addRow(newRow);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not the purpose of [`addRow()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/addrow). According to the docs, it *"Adds an empty data item to the grid"*, so it doesn't accepts any parameter and doesn't adds data to the grid.

You should add the new data with [`dataSource.add()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/add):

```
var newRow = {field1: $("#field1").val(), field2: $("#field2").val(), field3: $("#field3").val()};

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.add(newRow);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/ehONEjAM)

Answer (score 4):

Insert in the top of the Grid with grid.insert(0, dataItem);

Your sample:

```
var newRow = {field1: $("#field1").val(), field2: $("#field2").val(), field3: $("#field3").val()};

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.insert(0, newRow);
```